# CodeIgniter - It is possible to hook form_validation->set_rules in callback function?

Tags: php, codeigniter

Hi I got a problem in hooking validation through callback function. 
$this->form_validation->set_message is working but $this->form->validation->set_rules is not. TIA

```
<?php
if (!defined('BASEPATH')) {
  exit('No direct script access allowed');
}

class Users extends CI_Controller {
  public function validate_form() {

    $data = array('success' => false, 'messages' => array());

    $this->load->library('form_validation');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('Employed', '', 'required|callback_is_employed');
    $this->form_validation->set_error_delimiters('<p class="text-danger">','<br />','</p>');

    if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        $data['success'] = true;
    } else {
        foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
            $data['messages'][$key] = form_error($key);
        }
    }
    echo json_encode($data);
  }

  public function is_employed() {
    if($this->input->post('Employed')) {
        $this->form_validation->set_message('is_employed', 'data is checked');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('EmployedNoB', 'EmployedNoB', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('EmployedCA', 'EmployedCA', 'trim|required');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('EmployedCN', 'EmployedCN', 'trim|required');
        return false;
    }
  }
}
?>
```

Comment: callback function must return boolean or string. Now it returns false when  Employed is present, breaking validation process, and returns nothing in else case  (I don't know. how that interpreted by validation library)

Comment: Hi, thanks for the replied. Is there any way to work the set_rules in callback?

Comment: Why you want to do it in callback? Move `if` to other `set rules`

Comment: I want the users to check the box to verify if they employed or not. If checked then the hidden div box will display together with input text to validate.

Comment: Hi, I have already figured out. Thanks for the help